# SQL,DataTable. Why value changing in every row in column?

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable

So i  writed something like editor but I have problem with value changing in every row in one column. I want to change just one specific cell not all. Also I used breakpoints and I realize that it happens when  SqlCommand is defined and Executed but I don't know why it happens? I want e.g have two values the same but also want to it just change value in row which selected in comboxo not in all rows...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateBase();
        this.Close();
    }

    public string currentvalue = "";

    public void UpdateBase()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\JM\Documents\Kviz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 0);

        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 1);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 1);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 1);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 2);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 2);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 2);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 3);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 3);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 3);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 4);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 4);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 4);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 5)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 5);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 5);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 5);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 6)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 6);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 6);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 6);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 7)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 7);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 7);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 7);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 8)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 8);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 8);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 8);
        }
        else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 9)
        {
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 9);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 9);
            setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 9);
        }

    }




SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\JM\Documents\Kviz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
public void setRadioButtonText(RadioButton RadioButton,string RadioButtonColumn, int row)
{

    ////Determine which radiobutton in datatable's row is selected
          //!//
    if (RadioButton.Checked == true)
    {
           //!//   
        RadioButton.Text = textBox1.Text;
        ////GET CURRENT VALUE
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Pitanja", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
                              //!//       //!//
        currentvalue = dt.Rows[row][RadioButtonColumn].ToString();
        ////GET CURRENT VALUE
                                                                      //!//                                         //!//
        SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pitanja SET " + RadioButtonColumn + " = @textboxtext WHERE " + RadioButtonColumn + " LIKE '" + currentvalue + "'", con);
        comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textboxtext", textBox1.Text);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Me48.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in this part of your code

```
currentvalue = dt.Rows[row][RadioButtonColumn].ToString();
    ////GET CURRENT VALUE
                                                                  //!//                                         //!//
SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pitanja SET " + RadioButtonColumn + " = @textboxtext WHERE " + RadioButtonColumn + " LIKE '" + currentvalue + "'", con);
    comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textboxtext", textBox1.Text);
```

You retrieve the value of the radiobuttoncolumn and update all 'Pitanja' where the value of the radiobuttoncolumn is equal to this value. Since all of your rows in the database are equal to this value. They will all be updated.

You should choose a unique value to filter your update, like your ID column.
Then only the row with that unique Id will get updated.
It will probably look a bit like this, however I didn't test this.

```
currentvalue = dt.Rows[row]["Id"].ToString();
    ////GET CURRENT VALUE
                                                                  //!//                                         //!//
SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pitanja SET " + RadioButtonColumn + " = @textboxtext WHERE Id = " + currentvalue, con);
    comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textboxtext", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: What exception are you seeing? Or what makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your  objection, I'm not much active on the forums so I hope you do not mind.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried code which send HansVG but didn't notice what HansVG sayed "Since all of your rows in the database are equal to this value. They will all be updated.", so I tried with Id until it worked...

Here is how it look like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateujBazu();
    this.Close();
}

public string currentvalue = "";

public void UpdateujBazu()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\JM\Documents\Kviz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 0,1);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 0,1);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 0,1);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 1,2);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 1,2);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 1,2);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 2,3);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 2,3);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 2,3);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 3,4);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 3,4);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 3,4);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 4,5);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 4,5);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 4,5);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 5)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 5,6);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 5,6);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 5,6);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 6)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 6,7);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 6,7);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 6,7);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 7)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 7,8);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 7,8);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 7,8);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 8)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 8,9);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 8,9);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 8,9);
    }
    else if (Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 9)
    {
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton1, "RadioBtn1text", 9,10);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton2, "RadioBtn2text", 9,10);
        setRadioButtonText(Povezivac_varijabli_Formama.edi.radioButton3, "RadioBtn3text", 9,10);
    }

}




SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\JM\Documents\Kviz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
public void setRadioButtonText(RadioButton RadioButton,string RadioButtonColumn, int row,int ID)
{

    ////Determine which radiobutton in datatable's row is selected
          //!//
    if (RadioButton.Checked == true)
    {
           //!//   
        RadioButton.Text = textBox1.Text;
        ////GET CURRENT VALUE
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Pitanja", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
                              //!//       //!//
        currentvalue = dt.Rows[row][RadioButtonColumn].ToString();
        ////GET CURRENT VALUE
                                                                      //!//                                         //!//
        SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pitanja SET " + RadioButtonColumn + " = '" + textBox1.Text + "'" + " WHERE " + RadioButtonColumn + " LIKE '" + currentvalue + "'" + " AND Id = '"  + ID + "'", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznWN.jpg)